# Displaying Slider in Front Page (home) using Customizr Theme

Tags: php, functions, themes

I am using [Customizr Theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/customizr) on my website, and rendering its' front page, using a Static Page. Also I have two sidebars (left and right).

I used the static page, because when I put the slider it will appear above the sidebars. And I'm trying to put it in between the sidebars.

I added a **PHP snippet** in my child theme which would make it appear where I want it to.

```
function move_my_slider() {

    //we unhook the slider
   remove_action( '__after_header' , 
        array( TC_slider::$instance , 'tc_slider_display' ));

    //we re-hook the slider. Check the priority here : set to 0 to be the first in the list of different actions hooked to this hook 
   add_action( '__before_loop' , 
        array( TC_slider::$instance , 'tc_slider_display' ), 0);
}
```

This works fine as you can see where I tested it [here](http://www.sushidelivery.com.ph/test-page/). But when I tried using the *test-page* as front page, the slider does not appear? How can I include the slider in the front page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider displayed on front page is the one that you define **from the customizer option screen**. 
It overrides the one you have assigned to a page that you choose as front page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you I reverted my front page to displaying the latest post. And it worked, I guess I started out with wrong idea.